# How to use function in placeholder in md-select Angular?

Tags: angular

I tried to use that like:

```
<md-select
[placeholder]="getPlaceholder(subjects2)">

public getPlaceholder(values: any): string {
    return (Array.isArray(values) && values.length > 0 ) ? this.placeholders["1"] : this.placeholders["3"];
  }
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use quotes if you want to call an Array-field via index

```
public getPlaceholder(values: any): string {
    return (Array.isArray(values) && values.length > 0 ) ? 
           this.placeholders[1] : this.placeholders[3];
}
```